# Making a Drop Attack in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to make a drop attack for my character in 2D where if the attack button `Z` is pressed when the character is jumping, it'll swoop down as a diagonal line like a drop attack. My codes are below,

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anm;
private Collider2D coll;

private void Movement()
{
    float hDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if(!anm.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("attack"))
    {
        if (hDir < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speedX, rb.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1, 1);
        }
        else if (hDir > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedX, rb.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
        }
    }
    else if(anm.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("attack"))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && coll.IsTouchingLayers(ground))
    {
        Jump();
    }
}

private void Attack() {
    anm.SetTrigger("attack");
    if (!coll.IsTouchingLayers(ground)) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedX * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}

private void Jump() {
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpforce);
    state = State.jumping;
}
```

I think it has something to do at the `Attack()` function.

Comment: Explain what's your problem "I'm stumbling & looking for help" is not very descriptive.

Comment: It's not swooping down as a diagonal line to make a drop attack.

Comment: You are preserving Y velocity and setting X velocity based on time, if you want to do a diagonal then youy must set X to a fixed value and Y to a fixed negative value.

Comment: I tried like this, `rb.velocity = new Vector2(10, -20);` still not working.

Comment: "still not working" does not describe your problem, be more explicit.

Comment: rethink how to do all of your character controller without Animator.

Comment: @Gusman, What actually happens is the character instantly switches position, it should look like the character is swooping down to the position, not instantly appear in the position.

Comment: Try to use smaller speeds, maybe it's too fast and displaces it instantaneously to the final position.

Comment: Animator and Animator Controllers will drive you insane. As a concept for controlling game elements they're not good. For state, they're ok, but have issues. For animation control they're overkill. But the biggest issue is that they stand between you and having logical code that controls your character's movement and actions. Make your entire character controller work with code (switch statements), then consider how to manage any animations and aesthetics after you have everything else working, via code you understand totally and can control. DO NOT USE ANIMATOR CONTROLLERS. EVER!!!

Comment: @Gusman, how smaller should I use?